# Drop characters from string based on position

Tags: r

Is there an easy way to drop a specific character from a string.  In the example below, I would like to remove the last three characters from each element of the vector.

```
string<-c("Autauga AL", "Bald Win Av", "Barbour AL", "Bibb AL" ,   "Blount At" , "Bullock AL")
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What about `strtrim` and `nchar`?

```
strtrim(string, nchar(string)-3)
# [1] "Autauga"  "Bald Win" "Barbour"  "Bibb"     "Blount"   "Bullock"
```

You can also use the "stringi" package:

```
library(stringi)
stri_sub(string, 1, -4)
# [1] "Autauga"  "Bald Win" "Barbour"  "Bibb"     "Blount"   "Bullock"
```

The default for `stri_sub` is `to = -1L`, so to remove the last three characters it's `-1 - 3 = -4`.

Answer (score 6):

With `gsub()`, remove the three characters preceding `$` (the regex character representing "end of string"):

```
gsub(".{3}$", "", string)
[1] "Autauga"  "Bald Win" "Barbour"  "Bibb"     "Blount"   "Bullock"
```

Answer (score 0):

Another regex approach:

```
gsub("(.*)\\s.*", "\\1", string)
## [1] "Autauga"  "Bald Win" "Barbour"  "Bibb"     "Blount"   "Bullock"
```

Comment: It's worth noting that this regex keeps everything before the last space, not drops the last three characters. For the example data, the two operations give the same result (and this may be the semantics the OP wanted despite the question description), but the difference may be seen in different data.

Comment: Yeah Brian this relies on the space as I assumed this is what the data looks like.  The approach I have here could be useful if the last characters was not consistent (though I believe it is in this case).  I posted because this approach was a bit different than Josh's and a future searcher may find this approach more useful to their circumstances.