# Drop characters based on position

Tags: r, tidyverse

I would like to drop the characters `obovate` at second position

```
df <- data.frame(x = c("Antidesma obovate",
                       "Ardisia obovate", "Knema obovate", "Lauraceae obovate"))
```

My desired output

```
Antidesma
Ardisia
Knema
Lauraceae
```

I found one topic kind of answering my quesion ([Drop characters from string based on position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19323505/drop-characters-from-string-based-on-position))

but here I need to call specific character that I want to remove.
So far, I only know using `str_detect` to change the name right away e.g.

```
df %>% mutate(x= ifelse(str_detect(x, "Antidesma obovate"), "Antidesma ", x)) %>%
```

Any suggestions for me, please?

Comment: `sub("*.obovate","",df[,1])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We don't need `ifelse` or `str_detect` here.  Instead, use `str_remove` the remove the substring

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df %>% 
   mutate(x = str_remove(x, "\\s+obovate"))
          x
1 Antidesma
2   Ardisia
3     Knema
4 Lauraceae
```

Comment: thank you, lear more things today :D

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to use `gsub`:

```
gsub(" obovate", "", df$x)
```

Answer (score 2):

We could use `word` from `stringr` package:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df %>% 
  mutate(x = word(x,1))
```

Output:

```
          x
1 Antidesma
2   Ardisia
3     Knema
4 Lauraceae
```